# Photo upload error , what is wrong with my query

Tags: php

When I upload something other than jpg or png , it says Photo not updated. Please upload JPG or PNG photo only! but after that a follow up message comes , product updated successfully.
I want to remove only the follow up message.

```
 <?php

        include('session.php');
        $id=$_GET['id'];

        $p=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from product where productid='$id'");
        $prow=mysqli_fetch_array($p);

        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $category=$_POST['category'];
        $supplier=$_POST['supplier'];
        $price=$_POST['price'];
        $qty=$_POST['qty'];

        $fileInfo = PATHINFO($_FILES["image"]["name"]);

        if (empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])){
            $location=$prow['photo'];
        }
        else{
            if ($fileInfo['extension'] == "jpg" OR $fileInfo['extension'] == "png") {
                $newFilename = $fileInfo['filename'] . "_" . time() . "." . $fileInfo['extension'];
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" . $newFilename);
                $location = "upload/" . $newFilename;
            }
            else{
                $location=$prow['photo'];
                ?>
                    <script>
                        window.alert('Photo not updated. Please upload JPG or PNG photo only!');
                    </script>
                <?php
            }
        }

        mysqli_query($conn,"update product set product_name='$name', supplierid='$supplier', categoryid='$category', product_price='$price', photo='$location', product_qty='$qty' where productid='$id'");

        if($qty!=$prow['product_qty']){
            mysqli_query($conn,"insert into inventory (userid,action,productid,quantity,inventory_date) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."','Update Quantity', '$id', '$qty', NOW())");
        }
        ?>
            <script>
                window.alert('Product updated successfully!');
                window.history.back();
            </script>
        <?php

    ?>
```

Comment: But if you remove the follow up message, then it will never show, even when someone successfully uploads a JPG.

Comment: Move the part that performs the query into the `if ($fileInfo['extension'] == "jpg" OR $fileInfo['extension'] == "png") {` block

Comment: also, you introduce " $fileInfo = PATHINFO($_FILES["image"]["name"]); " without having previously defined "image."

Comment: @BooberBunz what happens is , even though its wrong the update successfull keeps popping out.

Comment: Oh look someone answered.

Comment: You only want to update when photo is jpg or png otherwise no update right??

Comment: @Nirali , I want the window.alert to only appear when it is successfull. But if not , no product successfully updated message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this.
Try one of possible solution

```
<?php

        include('session.php');
        $id=$_GET['id'];

        $p=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from product where productid='$id'");
        $prow=mysqli_fetch_array($p);

        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $category=$_POST['category'];
        $supplier=$_POST['supplier'];
        $price=$_POST['price'];
        $qty=$_POST['qty'];

        $fileInfo = PATHINFO($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $flag = 0;

        if (empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])){
            $location=$prow['photo'];
            $flag = 1;
        }
        else{
            if ($fileInfo['extension'] == "jpg" OR $fileInfo['extension'] == "png") {
                $newFilename = $fileInfo['filename'] . "_" . time() . "." . $fileInfo['extension'];
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" . $newFilename);
                $location = "upload/" . $newFilename;
                $flag = 1;
            }
            else{
                $location=$prow['photo'];
                ?>
                    <script>
                        window.alert('Photo not updated. Please upload JPG or PNG photo only!');
                    </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
        if($flag)
        {
        mysqli_query($conn,"update product set product_name='$name', supplierid='$supplier', categoryid='$category', product_price='$price', photo='$location', product_qty='$qty' where productid='$id'");

        if($qty!=$prow['product_qty']){
            mysqli_query($conn,"insert into inventory (userid,action,productid,quantity,inventory_date) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."','Update Quantity', '$id', '$qty', NOW())");
        }
        ?>
            <script>
                window.alert('Product updated successfully!');
                window.history.back();
            </script>
        <?php
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Tried it , the alert didint pop out but after that nothing happens , white screen.

Comment: In which case you are talking about?

Comment: it work , but after the pop out Photo not updated. Please upload JPG or PNG photo only! nothing happens , just white screen , it does not redirect to anywhere.

Comment: Because there is no statement written in your code where you want redirecting to

Comment: what should i add?  I thought the history.back will just redirect it to the last page.

Comment: Add header("Location: your url");
   exit;  OR if you want to in js <script type="text/javascript">location.href = 'newurl';</script>

Comment: Or you can also try <script>
             alert('message sent succesfully'); 
             window.history.go(-1);
     </script>"

Answer (score 0):

smpily move your updating code inside if condition - like

```
..
..
 if ($fileInfo['extension'] == "jpg" OR $fileInfo['extension'] == "png") {
      $newFilename = $fileInfo['filename'] . "_" . time() . "." . $fileInfo['extension'];
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" . $newFilename);
      $location = "upload/" . $newFilename;

      // write your update query here

      mysqli_query($conn,"update product set product_name='$name', supplierid='$supplier', categoryid='$category', product_price='$price', photo='$location', product_qty='$qty' where productid='$id'");
      if($qty!=$prow['product_qty']){
          mysqli_query($conn,"insert into inventory (userid,action,productid,quantity,inventory_date) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."','Update Quantity', '$id', '$qty', NOW())");
      }
     ?>
      <script>
            window.alert('Product updated successfully!');
            window.history.back();
        </script>
    <?php
  else{
      $location=$prow['photo'];
     ?>
      <script>
       window.alert('Photo not updated. Please upload JPG or PNG photo only!');
       </script>
      <?php
     }
    ?>
```

or you can use flag as suggested by @Nirali

Answer (score -1):

```
    # Please check below image upload code (Please do not forget it :- enctype="multipart/form-data") #


        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>

        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select image to upload:
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
        </form>

        </body>
        </html>

 # The "upload.php" file contains the code for uploading a file #

        <?php
        $target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false) {
                echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                $uploadOk = 1;
            } else {
                echo "File is not an image.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: I am new to programming , I dont quite understand complicated codes yet , but I think the only thing that is wrong with my code is adding an else if the upload is wrong to prevent the window.alert